# Can someone please explain .equ N, (. - myarray) / 2 to me?

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

So if you had

```
myarray:   .half 71, 92, 24, 59, 0x68, 10, 35, 34
```

The line of code below would assign the number of elements in myarray to symbol N.

```
.equ N, (. - myarray) / 2
```

I don't understand *how* this works. What does the   . -  part of the code really do?

(On PIC32MX360F256L with MPLAB 1.33 IDE)

Comment: _"The special symbol `.` refers to the current address that `as` is assembling into."_ I don't know if you're using `as` or some other assembler, but `.` probably has the same meaning for your assembler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify which assembler you are using, so this could be way off. I'm assuming you have some sort of `GNU as`-compatible, for MIPS, which supports the `.half` directive to declare half-words.

The `equ` directive sets the symbol `N` to the value of the expression `(. - myarray) / 2`.

In turn, `(. - myarray)` is the difference between `myarray`, the beginning of the array you declared, and the address `.`, the current address that `as` is assembling into.

Since `myarray` is an array of half-words (16-bits wide), dividing by 2 will make `N` equal to the *number of elements in `myarray`*, similar to the C expression: `sizeof myarray / sizeof *myarray`.

Answer (score 0):

It defines N to be half of the size of 'myarray'. Now when the elements of 'myarray' are (I guess) halfwords that would make symbol N the number of array elements.
The '-' is minus-sign (. - myarray) is current location (after array) minus the start address of 'myarray'.